# How-to implement a custom debugger visualiser in VS2008 on an array using a WeakReference?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, arrays, debuggervisualizer, weak-references

I would like to implement a custom debugger visualiser in vs2008 for a typical array as the standard one does not display the data as I would like it.  However Visual Studio prevents doing this for arrays for security reasons. I seem to remember though reading about using a `WeakReference` as a wrapper object to get around this limitation.

So for starters I would like to show something simple (C# code):

```
bool[] arrayOfBools = new bool[] { true, false, true, true, false };
```

Where the above is displayed as **`"10110"`**.

How could I do this using a `WeakReference`? Is there another way to do this?

For a longer array of bool types it would be useful to display them in a two dimensional grid say using a Uniform Grid layout control in WPF.

Comment: This is going to get me a tumbleweed badge!